# jit-lock message "it does not work in indirect buffer" does not allow me to use org-goto function

Tags: org-mode

I am having some trouble with that jit-lock message: *it does not work in indirect buffer*.

I think it is not related with my config files in *.emacs* because I tried the function without loading my *.emacs* and the issue persists.

So, I need a direction about what to do and what information should I provide you in order for helping me to fix that issue that's stopping me from using the **org-goto** function.

Please, note I understand very little about lisp-emacs, I usually grab some snippets from internet. That's why I am not very sure about what information should I provide.

Comment: No need to know about Lisp: just provide a step-by-step description of how you end up getting that message.  From what you write about all I know is that `org-goto` is somehow involved, but it's pretty fuzzy.

Comment: If you could provide a recipe for recreating the issue, starting from running `emacs -Q`, that should be sufficient for people to help figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If someone came to the same issue (or related), know that I solved it by **not loading twice** *org* from different packages (Elpa and Melpa) in Emacs.

Comment: Please accept your own answer. That prevents the question to pop up in the list again and again.